# Cambiar color de los tab bar items no seleccionados

Tags: ios, swift2, swift, xcode

me pregunto si alguien sabe como cambiar el color de los items de la tab bar en ios 9 , ahora mismo con el siguiente codigo solo se marca el seleccionado .

```
UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

**UPDATE SOLUCIONADO**

Encontre una manera de solucionar esto y lo publico por si ha alguien le interesa.
Cambie el color de las imagenes originales al color que me gustaría que tubieran sin estar seleccionadas .
Entonces hize lo siguiente:

1. Cambie el render de la imagen a : Original Image desde Assets.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Añadi este código para tintar el texto tanto en seleccionado como en no seleccionado.

   UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()], forState: .Normal)
   UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: .Selected)
3. En cada View controller indique la imagen de su tab item tanto en seleccionado como en no seleccionado , indicando también la renderización de la imagen ( ahi reside el truco para que el icono tinte al color seleccionado)

   ```
   self.tabBarItem.selectedImage =  UIImage(named: "home")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
   self.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "home")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
   ```
4. Y por supuesto añadí la linea de código en el Appdelegate con la que inicie la pregunta.

   UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

Answer (score 1):

Ya casi lo tienes con tu código. Simplemente utilizar `barTintColor` en lugar de `tintColor`:

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

El `tintColor` te modifica únicamente el color de la `UITabBar` **seleccionada** y en cambio el `barTintColor` te modifica **todas** las `UITabBar`.

Comment: Hey , pero lo que quiero no es tintar la tab bar si no sus items , con el barTintColor cambio el color del tab bar pero no de sus items , lo que quiero es que todos los items esten en blanco , no solo el seleccionado .http://i66.tinypic.com/2m6wffl.png

Comment: Entiendo, entonces quizá la mejor manera es modificar directamente la parte visual. ¿Cómo creas los UITabBar? ¿Puedes enseñarnos el códig/imagen? :) así te puedo dar una respuesta más concreta. Por ejemplo, si es con StoryBoard lo tendrías así: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29673404/1468942

Comment: Creo un tabbar controller por guión gráfico y despues asigno las imagenes por guión gráfico y en el appdelegate indico el trozo de código que publiqué .http://i65.tinypic.com/14ybd3q.png

Comment: Mira si el link que te he puesto te sirve, si te sirve actualizo la respuesta añadiendo detalles :)

Comment: Si ya lo tenía así también , la cosa es que así solo coge el color el item seleccionado y no todos , leí algo sobre renderizar la imagen del item pero tampoco me funcionó.